# How to initialize an array of vector<int> in C++ with predefined counts?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, stl, initialization

Excuse me, I'm new in STL in C++. How can I initialize an array of 10 vector pointer each of which points to a vector of 5 int elements.

My code snippet is as follows:

```
vector<int>* neighbors = new vector<int>(5)[10];  // Error
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't use `new`. A `std::array<std::array<int, 5>, 10>` sounds more like what you're asking for if you aren't changing the size and if my suspicions about the real need for pointers is correct.

Comment: The C++ equivalent would be a `vector<vector<int>>`. Any reason not to use that?

Comment: Would you please let me know more details? Or a sample code?

Comment: @juanchopanza: Yes, there are reasons not to use that (mostly that it's typically pretty inefficient).

Comment: First dimension of the array is always 10, but the second one may have different number of elements (at least 5)

Comment: In that case, you probably want `std::array<std::vector<int>, 10>`.

Comment: @RezaMortazavi, So change the inner one to a `std::vector`. It'll probably do for whatever your purpose is.

Comment: I want to pass the variable to some functions multiple times. Is it efficient way to use std::array (or a pointer is more efficient)?

Comment: @RezaMortazavi, Pass it by const reference if it isn't being changed and by non-const reference if it is. You should never need to pass by pointer for efficiency.

Comment: Thank you chris, Would you please add an answer. I want to vote it.

Comment: @RezaMortazavi, The existing one is fine.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I know the reasons, but I find it to be the closest equivalent to a dynamically allocated array of vector pointers (except that I dropped the inner pointer). The best structure depends on OP's actual needs.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This creates a vector containing 10 `vector<int>`, each one of those with 5 elements:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v(10, std::vector<int>(5));
```

Note that if the size of the outer container is fixed, you *might* want to use an `std::array` instead. Note the initialization is more verbose:

```
std::array<std::vector<int>, 10> v{{std::vector<int>(5), 
                                    std::vector<int>(5), 
                                    std::vector<int>(5), 
                                    std::vector<int>(5), 
                                    std::vector<int>(5),
                                    std::vector<int>(5), 
                                    std::vector<int>(5), 
                                    std::vector<int>(5), 
                                    std::vector<int>(5), 
                                    std::vector<int>(5)
                                    }};
```

Also note that the contents of array are part of the array. It's size, as given by `sizeof`, is larger than the `vector` version, and there is no O(1) move or swap operation available. An `std::array` is akin to a fixed size, automatic storage plain array.

Note also that, as @chris suggests in the comments, you can chose to set the elements of the array *after* a default initialization, e.g. with `std::fill` if they are all to have the same value:

```
std::array<std::vector<int>, 10> v; // default construction
std::fill(v.begin(), v.end(), std::vector<int>(5));
```

otherwise, you can set/modify the individual elements:

```
v[0] = std::vector<int>(5); // replace default constructed vector with size 5 one
v[1].resize(42); // resize default constructed vector to 42
```

and so on.

Comment: First dimenstion seems to be std::array (it has a constant number of elements). But, if it is efficient enough for passing to multiple functions. (please note that the numbers 5 and 10 are only for simplicity and in fact they may grow up to 1e6!)

Comment: Honestly, I'd prefer a `std::fill` to that initialization.

Comment: @chris Agreed. I added something about that.

Comment: @RezaMortazavi it is not particularly inefficient in general. What is inefficient is `swap` and `move`. O(N) instead of O(1).