# How to initialize an array of vector?

Tags: c++, vector

I know how to initialize a vector having a default value "val".

```
vector <int> v(size,val);
```

but I want to initialize ***an array of vector*** where each vector having a default value "val".....or if possible different values.

***declaration:***

```
vector <int> v[10];
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: `vector <int> v[10] = {
        {1,2,3},
        {4,5,6}, /*the rest*/
    };`?

Comment: what about `vector<vector<int> > v(10, vector<int>(size, val));`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to initialize an array of vector<int> in C++ with predefined counts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18159820/how-to-initialize-an-array-of-vectorint-in-c-with-predefined-counts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it....
there is an another way,too.
to create the two-dimensional vector of given size with default value "VAL":

```
int N, N; 
// ... 
vector< vector<int> > Matrix(N, vector<int>(M, VAL));
```

Comment: That matrix is terribly inefficient. Nesting vectors default memory layout hurts performance. That said, if it is for learning purposes, it is enough.

Comment: @GermánDiago True. The array of vectors is, in fact, already quite inefficient in that respect.

Answer (score 0):

A more generic version using c++11, where you don't need to repeat writing the vector constructors. It return an std::array

```
template <unsigned N>
auto make_array_of_vecs(std::size_t size, int val) {
   std::array<std::vector<int>, std::index_sequence<I...>::size()> arr;
   std::fill(begin(arr), end(arr), std::vector<int>(size, val));

   return arr;
 }
```

How to use:

```
auto array_of_vecs = make_array_of_vecs<10>(15, 10);
```

WARNING: Not tested.

Comment: You have to use `I` to let compiler expand `...`, something like `return {{ (I, std::vector<int>(size, val))... }};`